# Computer is loading old website but its not a caching issue

Tags: windows, web, ip-address

Ok so I just had a domain switch hosts today and everything is going fine except for a few minor things that I know how to fix. However there is one issue that I have not come across before. One computer is not loading the new website. Its loading the old one still. I know what you are thinking, its a caching issue. Nope, doesn't seem so. I erased all cache on chrome and refreshed and it still loads the old site.

So I whipped out my laptop, and re-tested and sure enough the new site is live. But here is where things get interesting, I pinged the site from my laptop and got the correct ip address and such. I did it on the other computer and I was getting a completely different ip address.

So I thought, ok there could be something in the hosts file that could be forcing it to point to the old website but I didn't see anything in the file that looked unusual. This computer is running Windows 8 and the hosts file I checked was located in

`C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

I don't know what else to check. Any guesses?

Thanks

Comment: It's a **DNS** caching issue.

Comment: Yeah maybe try flushing the DNS?

Comment: @SLaks Ok thats what it was. Had no idea Windows did that. Write it as an answer and I will give you the points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing a cached IP address from DNS.

Run `ipconfig /flushdns`, and go to `chrome://net-internals` and flush its DNS cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should flush your DNS. It can sometimes take a while for these things to be updated also. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The dns might need some time to get updated. You can check the dns settings on the machine and check they are hitting the same server (ipconfig -all). It may get fixed automatically just by waiting 96 hours.

You can try to change the DNS settings to target a server that got updated more frequently (e.g. google's 8.8.8.8).